# How do I structure my C++ project with multiple applications?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on implementing a BST in c++. The project needs two applications, one to read data from a file and build the tree and save it to a file. And another application to load then query the tree for information. I am trying to find a good structure for my entire project. I am thinking the source folder will contain three .cpp files: App1.cpp, App2.cpp and main.cpp. Is this how it's usually done?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a BST? Google gives British Summer Time to me, and I guess you are not talking about that. You probably need some header file, and you might want to build some [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29). But your question could be operating system specific. Maybe you want to have some [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Binary Search Tree lol

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I guess Binary Search Tree.

Comment: BTW, [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)-s are generally implemented with [self-balancing binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) such as [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) so you don't need to implement your own.